# "Forever we shall be" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found this cup on [flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com/hot-muggs-you-forever-shall-mug/p/itmdzq4hqgwqeamm?pid=MUGDZQ4HW3BZJZQW&icmpid=reco_pp_personalhistoryFooter_mug_1):

[image: Forever we shall be]

What does it mean actually? We shall live forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess was that the "we" on the cup refers to a couple; the phrase means:

> We will be [together] forever

or, said another way:

> We will be [a couple] forever

In other words, it's a statement of commitment or devotion.

Visiting the website, I noticed that the product description mentions a "love message," which seems to confirm my assumption.

The language is ambiguous, though, in that the sentence could be referring to anything. "Forever we shall be lonely" could be another valid interpretation, depending on the context:

> "Jill, you and I haven't had a significant other for three years now. I don't know why guys just don't seem interested in us. Lonely are we now, and forever we shall be...
>
> "That's why I got you this really nice mug for Christmas."

It's a deliberately poetic lingual construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill in the rest of the phrase with good words, as if it were written: ***"Forever, we shall be ..."***. This will have the same meaning to **"We shall be ... forever"**, but it sounds more poetic.

Here are some examples of good words for this phrase:

> *Forever, we shall be **friends**.*
>   *Forever, we shall be **together**.*
>   *Forever, we shall be **tied together**.*